# Please come back before 10 am vs by 10 am

Tags: meaning, prepositions, difference

> Please come back before 10 am.
>   Please come back by 10 am.

What's the difference in between?

Answer (score 2):

The meaning is roughly the same for both versions: you should arrive before 10, however there is a difference in when the two versions would be used.

**before** tends to be used when the action has no lasting effect. For example, if you have to pick up a document and then leave, but the person who has the document will be busy from 10am, then any time before 10am is acceptable, somebody would probably say:

> Please come back before 10 am

**by** tends to be used when the action has some lasting consequence that will still be in effect at the indicated time. For example, If you have a meeting with somebody at 10am, you need to arrive before 10am, and you **still need to be there at 10am**, somebody would probably say:

> Please come back by 10am

Another example for **by** would be if you have to submit a report before a certain date, because once a report is submitted it stays submitted.

> The report must be submitted by 1st May 2017.

Parents generally tell their children to be home **by** 10pm (ie they stay in once they have arrived) rather than **before** 10pm.

Comment: I don't think that there's necessarily any implication of remaining with "by" or leaving with "before"... I could easily say "I need to get back to the office before 2 pm [because I have a meeting that starts at 2]". The big difference I see here is that one of them must be completed **before** 2 pm (i.e. by 1:59 pm) and the other by 2:00 pm. I think you're overcomplicating it.

Comment: @Catija, I agree that you can use either in almost any situation, but I think that people tend to use **by** in a situation where the action has a lasting effect. For example, **visit** would go with before, and **be back** would go with **by**.

Comment: That's your personal preference, though... it doesn't mean anything. If I needed to say that I need to be back at the office for a 2 pm meeting, I don't think I have a preference between "by" or "before"... unless I'm emphasizing that I need to be back **before** 2 pm. I might even use both: "*I need to be back **before** 2 pm for a meeting, preferably **by** 1:30 so I can prep*.

Answer (score 0):

Please come back before 10 am

Please come back by 10 am.

The preposition "before" means earlier than the time mentioned, whereas the preposition "by" means not later than the time mentioned.

In the former sentence, you are reqesting the listener to be already back when it's 10 am, whereas  the latter sentence indicates that 10 am is the last point in time at which the listener can be back.

Comment: The question doesn't include "from"?

Comment: Your answer still says "from".

Comment: @Catija, Sorry for the typo. I have edited the answer.